# Android App Launcher strange behaviour

Tags: android, launcher

hi guys i am finding the strange behaviour in android while launching the Application. Let me explain the senerio. I am launching my application from android's launcher page and my application starts and runs fine and after few minute i press home button and go to android home page and then go to launcher page and again select my application and it is starting it again from first but it should have resumed from the last place where i left. And when i press back button on the launch screen of second instance of my app i am able to go back to the last page where i have left. I am more confused about what was happening and it too happens sometimes only not every time. Hope you people could help me sort this problem, Hoping for better responses. Thanks in Advance.

Edit #1:
It is not happening in all the device it happens only with Samsung and Sony but works fine with LG and HTC.

Answer (score 1):

To keep an activity running in the background is not in your hand. When you press the home button, your current activity goes to the background and can be killed (onDestroy() will be called) at any time depending on the need for memory of the other applications you launch.

The more apps you launch, the more chances of killing your background app is.

Comment: In my case i don't open any other application just come to home screen and then launch the application again, still it happens..

Comment: Opening an application just increases the chances of your background app being killed. Your app can be killed at any time as soon as it goes to background.

Comment: if it is being killed i will not be able to get to my last place where i left on back press from second instance.

Answer (score 0):

The behavior may be device specific - try saving your game settings in a persisted location within the 'onPause()' function, and retrieving it on 'onResume()'.  Then it doesn't matter if a new activity gets launched or the old one gets called.